# Get next id from the db table and assign suffix django 2

Tags: django, django-views

I am working on this issue for last few hrs and landed no where. Here is my problem.

I have a model that will track the shipments and I want to create the shipment number automatically when the form is loaded fro a new shipment. The logic is to get the next available Id from the database and add some test and store. My model is

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
shipmentNumber = models.CharField(max_length=50)
shipmentDate = models.DateTimeField()
dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
dateModified = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.shipmentNumber
```

and the view is

```
def createshipment(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CreateShipmentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        shipment = form.save(commit=False)
        shipment.shipmentNumber = request.shipmentNumber
        shipment.shipmentDate = timezone.now()
        shipment.save()
else:
    form = CreateShipmentForm()
    form.shipmentNumber = 'get the next id and assign suffix'

    context ={'form' : form}

return render(request,'../templates/mainSection/createshipment.html',context)
```

I tried to retrieve the data by getting all the shipments in the db and count them and go form there. But I ended up with "didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Any thought on how should I create the shipment number?

Thanks

Comment: The `didn't return an HttpResponse object` error is probably related to not returning an HttpResponse object in the POST method. But otherwise, creating shipment number before creating an object (before saving) is unreliable. Imagine having two users who open the form simultaneously. They'll both get the same shipment number and you'll end up with duplicate shipment numbers.

Comment: @Borut - Thank you for the insight. This application will not be use by concurrent users. That was the main reason that I motivated auto generate the shipment number so that it will be consistent across the application. How do I get the next ID though?